# Electromagnetic stress-energy tensor to be used in Einstein's Field Equations

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am trying to put in the electromagnetic energy-stress tensor in for the energy-momentum tensor of Einstein's field equations. 
I am, however, unsure as to which tensor matrix to use. I found the following tensor matrix from "Introduction to Einstein-Maxwell equations and the Rainich conditions" by Wytler Cordeiro Dos Santos:
$$ T_{mv} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2}(\epsilon |E|^{2} + \frac{1}{\mu}|B|^{2}) & -\frac{S_{x}}{c} & -\frac{S_{y}}{c} & -\frac{S_{z}}{c} \\
    -\frac{S_{x}}{c} & -\sigma_{xx} & -\sigma_{xy}  -\sigma_{xz} \\
    -\frac{S_{y}}{c} & -\sigma_{yx} & -\sigma_{yy}  -\sigma_{yz} \\
-\frac{S_{z}}{c} & -\sigma_{zx} & -\sigma_{zy} -\sigma_{zz} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

However the textbook definition of the electromagnetic energy-stress tensor is:
$$ T^{mv} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2}(\epsilon |E|^{2} + \frac{1}{\mu}|B|^{2}) & \frac{S_{x}}{c} & \frac{S_{y}}{c} & \frac{S_{z}}{c} \\
    \frac{S_{x}}{c} & -\sigma_{xx} & -\sigma_{xy}  -\sigma_{xz} \\
    \frac{S_{y}}{c} & -\sigma_{yx} & -\sigma_{yy}  -\sigma_{yz} \\
\frac{S_{z}}{c} & -\sigma_{zx} & -\sigma_{zy} -\sigma_{zz} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
with $\sigma_{ij} = \epsilon E_{i}E_{j} + \frac{1}{\mu}B_{i}B_{j} - \frac{1}{2}(\epsilon E^{2} + \frac{1}{\mu}B^{2})\delta_{ij} $

So which matrix equation would I use in Einstein's field equation:
$G_{\alpha\beta} = R_{\alpha \beta} - \frac{1}{2}g_{\alpha \beta}R = -\frac{8 \pi G}{c^{4}} T_{\alpha\beta}$?

Thanks. If any further information is needed please let me know.

Jay

edit:Fixed Einstein's Field Equation. If I was to want free space energy tensor which would I use?

Comment: The first tensor has two lower indices, the second has two upper indices.

Comment: Yes that is correct. That is how the paper I referenced has it (pg.13). This is why I am confused as to what electromagnetic stress energy tensor I can place into the energy-momentum tensor of Einstein's field equations.

Comment: Both of the expressions you give are only correct for flat spacetime I think. I've never done EM in curved spacetime, so am not sure but Wikipedia gives $T_{\mu\nu} = - \frac{1}{\mu_0} \left ( F_{\mu \alpha} g^{\alpha \beta} F_{\beta \nu} - \frac{1}{4} g_{\mu \nu} F_{\sigma \alpha} g^{\alpha \beta} F_{\beta \rho} g^{\rho \sigma} \right  ) $ as the correct expression for curved spaces.

Comment: @Jay: is the Einstein field equation you're using one with a stress-energy tensor with raised or lowered indices in the Stress-energy tensor?

Comment: Your answer is different if it is $R^{ab} - \frac{1}{2}Rg^{ab} = 8\pi T^{ab}$ versus $R_{ab}  - \frac{1}{2} R g_{ab} = 8\pi T_{ab}$

Comment: @jacob1729: *Both of the expressions you give are only correct for flat spacetime I think.* I don't think that's right. They assume a local orthonormal chart, but the form of the tensor doesn't change based on curvature. Tensors exist in the tangent space, which is a fictitious flat space.

Comment: You should be consistent with your index notation.

Comment: @BenCrowell the actual numbers in $T$ include the components of $g$ though (see the formula in my comment or in the current answer). For instance, OPs two expressions are related by index lowering with the Minkowski metrix $\eta$ - if one of these is numerically correct for some $g\neq \eta$ then the other one must be wrong since the index raising should be happening with $g$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this answers your question, but I think it might help.

First of all your field equation is messed up. What you want is 
$$R_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R = \kappa T_{\mu\nu}$$ 
or this
$$R^{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}R = \kappa T^{\mu\nu}$$ 
The stress energy tensor in electromagnetism can be derived from the Lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{\sqrt{-g}}{4} F^{\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}$$
It comes out to be 
$$T_{\mu\nu} = F^{\beta}_{\mu}F_{\beta\nu} - \frac{1}{4}g_{\mu\nu}F^{\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}$$
The expression will be similar in covariant form. Plugging this into the Einstein field equations
$$R_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=\kappa(F^{\beta}_{\mu}F_{\beta\nu} - \frac{1}{4}g_{\mu\nu}F^{\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta})$$

Also a bit of advice: you should use 
$$R_{\mu\nu}=\kappa(T_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}T)$$
Instead of $G_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu\nu}$. It is easier to solve.

**FYI: 1. All formulae are in natural units.**
        **2. $F_{\mu\nu}$ is [Electromagnetic field tensor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor).**