# Derivation of the Electromagnetic Stress-Energy Tensor in Flat Space-time

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am working on deriving the electromagnetic stress energy tensor using the electromagnetic tensor in the $(-, +, +, +)$ sign convention. However, I have hit a snag and cannot figure out where I have gone wrong.

$$ F^{\mu \alpha}= 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{E_{x}}{c} & \frac{E_{y}}{c} & \frac{E_{z}}{c} \\
    -\frac{E_{x}}{c} & 0 & B_{z} & -B_{y} \\
    -\frac{E_{y}}{c} & -B_{z} & 0 &  B_{x} \\
    -\frac{E_{z}}{c} & B_{y} & -B_{x} & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
F^{\mu}_{\alpha} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{E_{x}}{c} & \frac{E_{y}}{c} & \frac{E_{z}}{c} \\
    \frac{E_{x}}{c} & 0 & B_{z} & -B_{y} \\
    \frac{E_{y}}{c} & -B_{z} & 0 &  B_{x} \\
    \frac{E_{z}}{c} & B_{y} & -B_{x} & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{\mu_0}(F^{\mu \alpha}F^{v}_{\alpha} - \frac{1}{4}\eta^{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha \beta})$$

Doing matrix multiplication of the matrices $F^{\mu \alpha}$ and $F^{\nu}_{\alpha}$ from above gives

$$
F^{\mu \alpha}F^{\nu}_{\alpha} =
 \begin{bmatrix}
 (\frac{E}{c})^{2} & -B_{z}\frac{E_{y}}{c} + B_{y}\frac{E_{z}}{c}  & \frac{E_{x}}{c}B_{z} - \frac{E_{z}}{c}B_{x} & -\frac{E_{x}}{c}B_{y} + \frac{E_{y}}{c}B_{x} \\
 B_{z}\frac{E_{y}}{c} - B_{y}\frac{E_{z}}{c} & -B_{z}^{2} - B_{y}^{2} - (\frac{E_{x}}{c})^{2} & -\frac{E_{x}}{c}\frac{E_{y}}{c} + B_{y}B_{x} & \frac{E_{x}}{c}\frac{E_{z}}{c} + B_{z}B_{x} \\
 -B_{z}\frac{E_{x}}{c} + B_{x}\frac{E_{z}}{c} & -\frac{E_{y}}{c}\frac{E_{x}}{c} + B_{x}B_{y} & -(\frac{E_{y}}{c})^{2}-B_{z}^{2}-B_{x}^{2} & -\frac{E_{y}}{c}\frac{E_{z}}{c} + B_{z}B_{y} \\
 B_{y}\frac{E_{x}}{c} - B_{x}\frac{E_{y}}{c} & -\frac{E_{z}}{c}\frac{E_{x}}{c} + B_{x}B_{z} & -\frac{E_{z}}{c}\frac{E_{y}}{c} + B_{y}B_{z} & -(\frac{E_{z}}{c})^{2}-B_{y}^{2}-B_{x}^{2} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Subtracting the $\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}= \frac{1}{4}\eta^{\mu\nu}[2(B^{2} - (\frac{E}{c})^{2})]$ and multiplying by $\frac{1}{\mu_{0}}$ gives

$$ T^{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{\mu_{0}}  
   \begin{bmatrix}
 (\frac{E}{c})^{2} + \frac{1}{2}(B^{2} - (\frac{E}{c})^{2}) & -B_{z}\frac{E_{y}}{c} + B_{y}\frac{E_{z}}{c}  & \frac{E_{x}}{c}B_{z} - \frac{E_{z}}{c}B_{x} & -\frac{E_{x}}{c}B_{y} + \frac{E_{y}}{c}B_{x} \\
 B_{z}\frac{E_{y}}{c} - B_{y}\frac{E_{z}}{c} & -B_{z}^{2} - B_{y}^{2} - (\frac{E_{x}}{c})^{2} - \frac{1}{2}(B^{2} - (\frac{E}{c})^{2}) & -\frac{E_{x}}{c}\frac{E_{y}}{c} + B_{y}B_{x} & \frac{E_{x}}{c}\frac{E_{z}}{c} + B_{z}B_{x} \\
 -B_{z}\frac{E_{x}}{c} + B_{x}\frac{E_{z}}{c} & -\frac{E_{y}}{c}\frac{E_{x}}{c} + B_{x}B_{y} & -(\frac{E_{y}}{c})^{2}-B_{z}^{2}-B_{x}^{2} - \frac{1}{2}(B^{2} - (\frac{E}{c})^{2}) & -\frac{E_{y}}{c}\frac{E_{z}}{c} + B_{z}B_{y} \\
 B_{y}\frac{E_{x}}{c} - B_{x}\frac{E_{y}}{c} & -\frac{E_{z}}{c}\frac{E_{x}}{c} + B_{x}B_{z} & -\frac{E_{z}}{c}\frac{E_{y}}{c} + B_{y}B_{z} & -(\frac{E_{z}}{c})^{2}-B_{y}^{2}-B_{x}^{2} - \frac{1}{2}(B^{2} - (\frac{E}{c})^{2}) \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

However, the textbook definition of the electromagnetic stress energy tensor is:
$$ T^{\mu\nu} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2}(\epsilon_{0} |E|^{2} + \frac{1}{\mu_{0}}|B|^{2}) & \frac{S_{x}}{c} & \frac{S_{y}}{c} & \frac{S_{z}}{c} \\
    \frac{S_{x}}{c} & -\sigma_{xx} & -\sigma_{xy}  & -\sigma_{xz} \\
    \frac{S_{y}}{c} & -\sigma_{yx} & -\sigma_{yy}  & -\sigma_{yz} \\
\frac{S_{z}}{c} & -\sigma_{zx} & -\sigma_{zy} & -\sigma_{zz} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
with $\vec{S} = \frac{1}{\mu_{0}}(\vec{E} \times \vec{B})$ and $\sigma_{ij} = \epsilon_{0} E_{i}E_{j} + \frac{1}{\mu_{0}}B_{i}B_{j} - \frac{1}{2}(\epsilon_{0} E^{2} + \frac{1}{\mu_{0}}B^{2})\delta_{ij} $

So, I know my $T^{01} = T^{10}$, $T^{02} = T^{20}$, and $T^{03} = T^{30}$ but they do not. They are of opposite signs. What did I do incorrectly?

Comment: Related posts by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476037/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476673/2451

Comment: my2cts: To get $F^{m}_{\alpha}$ wouldn't you essentially just change the signs of $F^{10}$, $F^{20}$, and $F^{20}$, (the last three components of the first column) of the $F^{m \alpha}$ matrix, since we are lowering the $\alpha$ index?

Answer (score 0):

You could do yourself a big favor by working in units with $c=1$. It's really cumbersome writing all the factors of $c$. You can always reinsert them at the end if you want a result in SI. Or if you want to compare with Wikipedia's equation that's expressed in SI, just drop all the $c$'s from WP's version.

You detected the problem because the final result lacked the proper symmetry. So look at your calculation for the first place where that symmetry is lost. This happens at the very first step, where you calculate $F^{\mu\alpha}F^\mu{}_\alpha$. This should be the same as $g_{\beta\alpha}F^{\mu\alpha}F^{\nu\beta}$, which is manifestly symmetric in $\mu$ and $\nu$. For example, its 01 component is $F^{02}F^{12}g_{22}+F^{03}F^{13}g_{33}=E_yB_z-E_zB_y$, which is the same as its 10 component. I think the problem is that you say you found this result by matrix multiplication. The ordinary rules of matrix multiplication assume that both matrices are written in mixed upper-lower index form.

Also note that in general there is a distinction between $T^\mu{}_\nu$ and $T_\nu{}^\mu$, so you can't just write $T^\mu_\nu$ without ambiguity. If this was just an issue with mathjax, the syntax that works is this: `T^\mu{}_\nu`.

Comment: How did you get $F^{02}F^{12}g_{22}+F^{03}F^{13}g_{33}$ for the 01 component from $g_{\beta\alpha}F^{\mu\alpha}F^{\nu\beta}$? I found a paper for an introduction to Einstein-Maxwell equations and it seemed to me he just did straight matrix multiplication for that step. So, I am unsure as how you arrived at the formula for that sum.

Comment: Could I use plain old matrix multiplication with the matrices of $g_{\beta\alpha}F^{\mu\alpha}F^{\nu\beta}$, since $g_{\beta\alpha}$, $F^{\mu\alpha}$, and $F^{\nu\beta}$ are either upper or lower form and not mixed?

Comment: *How did you get F02F12g22+F03F13g33 for the 01 component from gβαFμαFνβ?* By applying the Einstein summation convention and writing down the two nonvanishing terms. *I found a paper for an introduction to Einstein-Maxwell equations and it seemed to me he just did straight matrix multiplication for that step.* Matrix multiplication $AB=C$ is represented in index notation as $A^\mu{}_\nu B^\nu{}_\lambda=C^\mu{}_\lambda$. That is, all three matrices, A, B, and C, have to be in mixed upper-lower form. You can't apply the rules of matrix multiplication to tensors that aren't expressed this way.

Comment: *Could I use plain old matrix multiplication with the matrices of gβαFμαFνβ, since gβα, Fμα, and Fνβ are either upper or lower form and not mixed?* No, that doesn't work.

Comment: So, the Einstein summing convention like I did in my other posted answer? Sorry, I had to post as an answer not a comment, as it was too long.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...I have done a little more work and I think I have it.
If 
$$ F^{\mu \alpha}= 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{E_{x}}{c} & \frac{E_{y}}{c} & \frac{E_{z}}{c} \\
    -\frac{E_{x}}{c} & 0 & B_{z} & -B_{y} \\
    -\frac{E_{y}}{c} & -B_{z} & 0 &  B_{x} \\
    -\frac{E_{z}}{c} & B_{y} & -B_{x} & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$ T^{mv} = \frac{1}{\mu_0}(F^{\mu \alpha}F^{\nu}{}_{\alpha} - \frac{1}{4}\eta^{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha \beta})$$
then letting c = 1
$$
F^{\mu \alpha}F^{v}{}_{\alpha} = \eta_{\beta\alpha}F^{\mu\alpha}F^{\nu\beta}
$$
If we let $\mu = 0,1,2,3$, $\nu = 0, 1, 2, 3$, and $\alpha=\beta$ summing over repeated indexes gives

for $\mu = 0$ and $\nu = 0$

$$
\eta_{\beta \alpha}F^{0\alpha}F^{0\beta} = \eta_{00}F^{00}F^{00}+\eta_{11}F^{01}F^{01}+ \eta_{22}F^{02}F^{02} + \eta_{33}F^{03}F^{03} = E_{x}^{2} + E_{y}^{2} + E_{z}^{2}
$$

for $\mu = 1$ and $\nu = 0$

$$
\eta_{\beta \alpha}F^{1\alpha}F^{0\beta} = \eta_{00}F^{10}F^{00}+\eta_{11}F^{11}F^{01}+ \eta_{22}F^{12}F^{02} + \eta_{33}F^{13}F^{03} = B_{z}E_{y} - B_{y}E_{z}
$$

and so on...

Is this correct? When looking at the indexes for the metric will $\alpha=\beta$ always be true when working in general relativity?

Answer (score 0):

With your notation, $F^{0i} = E_i/c = -F^{i0}$, for $i = 1, 2, 3$, $F^{ij} = B^k = -F^{ji}$, as $(i,j,k)$ ranges over $(1,2,3)$, $(2,3,1)$ and $(3,1,2)$ (i.e. where $i,j,k$ are "cyclic"), and $F^{μμ} = 0$, for $μ = 0, 1, 2, 3$.

With your convention, $(-,+,+,+)$, the metric is a proper distance metric (as opposed to a proper time metric) and has the components $g_{00} = -c^2$, and for $i,j = 1, 2, 3$: $g_{i0} = 0 = g_{0j}$ and $g_{ij} = δ_{ij}$, where $δ$ denotes the Kronecker delta, which has the components $δ_{ij} = 1$ if $i = j$ and $δ_{ij} = 0$ if $i ≠ j$.

The question you're actually asking is why your calculation fails to get $F^{0α}F^i_α = F^{iα}F^0_α$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$.

You've not made it clear which index is being lowered by the metric to get $F^μ_α$ from $F^{μν}$; but, going by context, you're lowering the second index, which means $F^i_0 = -c^2 F^{i0} = c E_i$, $F^0_i = F^{0i} = E_i/c$, for $i = 1, 2, 3$ and $F^i_j = F^{ij} = B^k$, where $i,j,k$ are cyclic.

Your left-most column in the second matrix should have $c$ in the numerator, not in the denominator.

A matrix product contracts the *last* index of the first matrix with the *first* index of the second matrix, while you're contracting the last indices of both matrices in the expression $F^{μα}F^ν_α$. You have to use the transpose of the second matrix. So, you have the wrong sign on the components $F^i_j$ as $i,j = 1,2,3$; and now it's the top row that has the $c$'s in the numerator, while the left-most column has the $c$'s in the denominator.

So, your second matrix is wrong: (1) the $c$'s go in the numerator on the top-most row and (2) the signs of the $(i,j)$ entries flip, for $i, j = 1, 2, 3$.

Thus $F^{iα}F^0_α = F^{ij}F^0_j + F^{ik}F^0_k = \left(B^kE_j - B^jE_k\right)/c = (×)^i/c$, where $i,j,k$ are cyclic and where I'm using the vectors $ = \left(E_1, E_2, E_3\right)$ and $ = \left(B^1, B^2, B^3\right)$. That's the bottom three entries on the left-most column. That matches what you have.

But, $F^{0α}F^i_α = F^{0j}F^i_j + F^{0k}F^i_k = \left(E_jB^k - E_kB^j\right)/c = (×)^i/c$, where $i,j,k$ are cyclic. That's the right-most three entries on the top row. That's the opposite sign of what you have.